# Wordpress font not loading in Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

In my Wordpress website I have set up the Klavika font as followed:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'klavika';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('path/fonts/KlavikaCH-Regular.otf'),
      url('path/fonts/KlavikaCH-Regular.woff2') format("woff2"),
      url('path/fonts/KlavikaCH-Regular.woff') format("woff"),
      url('path/fonts/KlavikaCH-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
```

When I open the website on the mobile in Google Chrome, the font shows, but when I open it in Safari, the font doesn't show. Why is this the case?

I added the formatting lines, but they didn't seem to help at all.

I added the formatting lines, but they didn't seem to help.

Comment: What OS/device(s) are you using and where are the fonts stored?

Comment: I checked it on iOS 17.1.2, but it doesn't seem to work on other versions too, as my coworker saw an incorrect font as well. 

The fonts are stored inside the Wordpress project.

Comment: Please inspect your page in dev tools and check the network tab filtered by fonts. If your paths are correct you should see entries for the font files. You can also savely remove the .otf file in your rule. woff2 and woff are well supported